# Help Merging Accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts

So I found out today when trying to change my email in my account that I already had an account registered to that email. So I'd like to combine my two accounts, but the merge instructions aren't helping (I can't change my login information to match, otherwise I wouldn't have discovered the second account to begin with).

I tried adding my Google account as an alternate to both accounts but I can't log into the other account now, I just get logged back into this one automatically (even when clearing cookies, and logging in with my other account's information...).

Answer (score 1):

Use [this link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge) for when you don't have access to the second account.

Ignore the fact that it says you need to edit the "about me" section of both profiles - because clearly you can't. Supply as much information as you can:

- the e-mail address on the second account.
- IP addresses you would have accessed it from.
- etc.

Comment: I added some info, and I think I know how I broke logging into the other one, when I hit the button to link my Google account, I was signed into two Google accounts - one of them was the email the second account was using (and the other was the one I intended). I'm guessing it linked to that one instead, so now I get logged into this account when I use that email.

Comment: Turns out my home PC was logged into the other one, so I managed to add a link to this account in the about me of the other account and vice-versa. Tried to link my Google account to it as well but it said it already belonged to another user (i.e. this account)...which doesn't explain why my login for that account now logs me into this one.